# Using multiple shaders on iOS, from two concurrent threads

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es

I am using an `GLKView` with some simple *shaders* to draw my content to the screen, but also want to use the GPU to do some hard calculations that are going to be needed in the app. With `glUseProgram` I can change the current shader in use, but I have a doubt on how it would work in reality (I'm going to test soon):

if the view rendering is on the **main thread** and the calculations are on a **background thread**, would there be racing conditions between the textures I use, or the current program that is loaded (say I fire `glUseProgram` for every update of the delegate for the `GLKView`)?

**UPDATE:**

it sounds like a situation in which multiple contexts would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need multiple contexts. As you may have multiple contexts on a single thread you should never have one context on multiple threads. The context itself will keep track of all states and no racing is needed.

You must know that having multiple contexts will make items like textures invisible between the contexts: if you create a texture on one context you may not use it on another. To overcome this you need a share group and initialize the background context with that share group. How this share groups work is you can not allocate one at all, you may only get a reference from an existing context.

So... Create the main context, then get the share group (a context property). Then create the background thread, on it create the new context using your share group in initializer and set it as the current. Note that on a separate context you will need to do all the work again such as binding the buffer, setting the viewport...

After you have done all that you should still consider the architecture of getting the notifications for when a certain operation has been finished. For instance if you wish to load a texture in background it is best that the background texture creates the actual texture and sends the data to it and on completion all you get is a texture ID.

The best practice of this I had come up with is to create a class that holds the context itself and a thread or a queue (even if it is a main thread). This class has methods `performBlock:` and `performBlock:callback:` where both invoke the block on its bound thread. Doing so you will never need to worry about what thread you are calling an openGL operation on or serialization, it all becomes transparent.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I do not need share groups, as the tasks of each thread are completely separate. Your class encapsulation sounds nice.